Yocto build - new machine, failing to build u-boot and tf-a for STM32MP1
I'm new to Yocto and need some guidance as I have already tried several approaches.
I'm building an image for a custom board with STM32MP157C, it's using Phytec phyCORE-STM32MP15x, in the source code (Phytec BSP) it's marked as phycore-stm32mp1-3.
BSP version: BSP-Yocto-OpenSTLinux-STM32MP1-PD23.1.0, it uses Yocto kirkstone.
Question
I can build the Linux kernel fine with my device tree from my layer and see it has correct content in yocto/build-openstlinuxweston-racer-board/tmp-glibc/deploy/images/racer-board/kernel/stm32mp157c-racer-board--5.15.67-stm32mp-r2-r0.4-racer-board-20240423132901.dtb
However, I fail to build u-boot for the custom machine. What is the recommended way to add my device tree, or which .dts files should I base on for basic functionality of loading the kernel? I want to handle additional hardware like display etc. only in kernel, don't need any changes in tf-a or u-boot in comparison to SoM/devkit dts files of phycore-stm32mp1-3.
I can build and boot the image for the already existing Phytec target.
Detailed description of the problem
I follow instructions from https://www.phytec.de/cdocuments/?doc=sQAeLg to create a new layer for my machine:

Initialize BSP for the new machine, distribution OpenSTLinux "Weston" (fully-featured distribution) DISTRO=openstlinux-weston MACHINE=racer-board BSP_DEPENDENCY=layers/meta-phytec source layers/meta-phytec/scripts/envsetup.sh
I create a new Yocto layer - it's recommended to create a new layer when making changes for a custom board:

bitbake-layers create-layer meta-racer
mv meta-racer ../layers/


In the layer, I have following layout, created according to the doc:

meta-racer
├── racer-board
│   └── CA7
│       └── DeviceTree
│           └── racer-board
│               ├── kernel
│               │   └── stm32mp157c-racer-board.dts
│               ├── tf-a
│               │   ├── stm32mp157c-racer-board-fw-config.dts
│               │   └── stm32mp157c-racer-board.dts
│               └── u-boot
│                   ├── stm32mp157c-racer-board-u-boot.dtsi
│                   └── stm32mp157c-racer-board.dts
├── conf
│   ├── eula
│   │   ├── racer-board -> ST_EULA_SLA
│   │   └── ST_EULA_SLA
│   ├── layer.conf
│   └── machine
│       └── racer-board.conf
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
└── recipes-example
   └── example
       └── example_0.1.bb



In the above layout, I don't know where to take the u-boot DTS from, so I take it from u-boot/arch/arm/dts/stm32mp157c-phycore-som-emmc-1gib.dts (and corresponding *-u-boot.dtsi), which I obtain using devtool modify -x u-boot-stm32mp . I later devtool reset u-boot-stm32mp so it doesn't affect the build. DTS files renamed to match the racer-board- prefix.
Similarly for tf-a, I copy and rename tf-a/fdts/stm32mp157c-phycore-som-emmc-1gib.dts and corresponding *-fw-config.dts to my layer.

Kernel build succeeds with bitbake linux-stm32mp.

Build the image: bitbake st-image-weston

u-boot build fails with binman: Device tree 'u-boot.dtb' does not have a 'binman' node Full output:


| binman: Device tree 'u-boot.dtb' does not have a 'binman' node
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/filip/yocto/build-openstlinuxweston-racer-board/tmp-glibc/work/racer_board-ostl-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-stm32mp/v2021.10-stm32mp-r2-r0/build/phycore-stm32mp15_defconfig'
| make[1]: *** [/home/filip/yocto/build-openstlinuxweston-racer-board/tmp-glibc/work-shared/racer-board/uboot-source/Makefile:1095: all] Error 1
| make: *** [Makefile:177: sub-make] Error 2
| make: Leaving directory '/home/filip/yocto/build-openstlinuxweston-racer-board/tmp-glibc/work-shared/racer-board/uboot-source'
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/filip/yocto/layers/meta-st/meta-st-stm32mp/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-stm32mp_2021.10.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'


The same fail can be also reproduced with just bitbake u-boot-stm32mp or bitbake tf-a-stm32mp.
